# xfreerdp keeps disconnecting

Tags: linux, freerdp

I'm logging into an rdp environment using Linux.

Everything works fine if the session is constantly in use.  However, if the user walks away from his/her desk, and comes back say 5 minutes later, the session has automatically closed, and the user has to connect again.

Anyway to stop this from happening?

---

The terminal shows the following message when the session is closed:

```
rpc_client_on_fragment_receiving_event: Receiving Out-of_sequence RTS PDU
Network disconenct!
Failed to check FreeRDP file descriptor
```

Comment: Can you check if any error messages are being displayed on the terminal after the session gets closed.

Comment: @beginer, I've added the details you requested to the question.

Comment: Have you `strace` ? Post it's output via pastebin

Comment: @SHW, how do I use strace.  Do I type strace in the terminal and then run the rds command?

Comment: It might be useful: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1202 info about patch sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of any network firewall in the path? That's usually the problem when a connection stays idle for too long - network equipment may terminate the connection.

I can't seem to find decent documentation on the internet about xfreerdp. Sending keep-alive probes or auto-reconnecting usually solve that problem, but it looks like [xfreerdp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xfreerdp) supports [neither](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/193).

Have you considered switching to [remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Yes, firewalls are in the path.  I can't switch to remmina because it does not support TSG (Terminal Services Gateway for RDS).